# Ugrading cert-manager from 0.12 to 1.11

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, cert-manager

I have k8s cluster with version 1.21 and cert-manager (v0.12) which was installed via helm. As far as I understand I should upgrade cert-manager version-by-version but I can't find CRDs file for version 0.13 (https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/releases/download/v0.13/cert-manager.crds.yaml - there is no such file. CRDs were installed separately from cert-manager).
So, guys, help me!

Answer (score 1):

I can get a file from this [URL](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/releases/download/v0.13.0/cert-manager.yaml); please test it and let me know how it works. When upgrading from earlier versions, use this file, which contains all of the Custom Resource Definitions (CRDs) for cert-manager 0.13.

You can upgrade using static manifests also by running the below command:

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/releases/download/<version>/cert-manager.yaml
```

You can find more information in this [doc](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/upgrading/#upgrading-using-static-manifests).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Do you know if it's possible to upgrade cert-manager from v0.12 straight to 1.11. (So, I just want to skip the upgrading steps 0.12->0.13, 0.13->0.14, 0.14-0.15 and etc)?

Comment: For upgrading to version 1.11 the minimum version required for upgrading is version 0.13, so after upgrading to 0.13 try using `kubectl apply -f https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.11.0/cert-manager.yaml` and let me know if this works.

Comment: It doesn't work from side. When I tried to `kubectl apply -f https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.11.0/cert-manager.crds.yaml` (cause cert-manager was installed via helm) - there is an error:
`Error from server (Invalid): error when applying patch: ...to:
Resource: "apiextensions.k8s.io/v1, .....CustomResourceDefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io "clusterissuers.cert-manager.io" is invalid: status.storedVersions[0]: Invalid value: "v1alpha2": must appear in spec.versions.`
I've skipped whole error message because there is no place for it

Comment: then you have to upgrade manually :(